# Get Requested URL

Tags: vb.net, tcplistener

I have been trying to read any requested URLs to my localhost. I think the simplest way to do this is to use the TCPListener. Below is what I've built so far but I'm not sure how I can read the URL requested as a string. I actually want to take the first incoming URL, parse out the data I need then shut the TCPlistener down. Any idea how I can get the URL?

```
Dim TClient As New TcpListener(Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 80)
TClient.Start()
Dim gotIt As Boolean = False
Do While gotIt = False
    Dim x = TClient.AcceptTcpClient()
    Console.WriteLine(x)
    TClient.Stop()
Loop
```

Comment: I'm starting to believe this just isn't possible? I usually have an answer by now if it's simple. Hope slipping.. :p

Comment: Have you tried reading the data that comes into the connection? The documentation includes an example of how to do that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an example from the MSDN I was able to come up with this:

```
    Dim server As TcpListener = Nothing

    Dim port As Int32 = 80
    Dim localAddr As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")
    server = New TcpListener(localAddr, port)
    server.Start()
    Dim bytes(1024) As Byte
    Dim data As String = Nothing

    Dim client As TcpClient = server.AcceptTcpClient
    data = Nothing
    Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream
    Dim i As Int32
    i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)

    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i)

    client.Close()
    server.Stop()
```

The data variable contains the information I am looking for, just have to parse it out.

Thank you, @CoderDennis

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the Referer header.

```
String requestedUrl = request.getHeader("Referer");
```

Mind that *Referer* is case sensitive.

100% working!